# ionic-native/network-interface, gives error the 'plugin not installed'?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I am using ionic-native/network-interface for getting the ip address of wifi I am connected with but It gives error Plugin not installed but I have installed it using official documentation.

**This is the code I have written**

```
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private networkInterface: NetworkInterface ) {

    this.networkInterface.getWiFiIPAddress().then(a=>alert(a)).catch(e=>alert(e));
  }
}
```

**Error:**

> plugin not installed

And I have addeed NetworkInterface in the providers in app.module.ts

Comment: call npm install then restart the project. See if it fixes

Comment: still not working

Comment: check whether it is in your package.json, there should be something like this "cordova-plugin-networkinterface": "^x.x.x",

Comment: yeah it is there  "@ionic-native/network-interface": "^4.9.0",

Comment: sorry  "cordova-plugin-networkinterface": {},

Comment: how are you running this app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In resume, ionic cache is boring. These lines helped me.

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-networkinterface -f
$ ionic cordova platform add browser
$ ionic cordova run browser
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:
Use this: Run "ionic cordova platform add [platform]" then "ionic cordova build [platform]" and run in your device. 
It worked for me!.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using capacitor 2.2.1 and I had the same problem "plugin_not_installed"... I was missing the actual module, at the end I did this:

`ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-networkinterface`

`npm install @ionic-native/network-interface`

`npm install cordova-plugin-networkinterface`